# Facebook Graph API fetch comments from og:type=website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I am trying to fetch comments from a Open Graph Object of type **website**.

I am testing all of this on the official Graph API Explorer page, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

First I paste the URL from the page which holds the Facebook comments on their page. And I get something like this:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "id_of_the_object",
    "description": "some_description",
    "title": "some_title",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2017-03-30T08:35:44+0000"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 5,
    "share_count": 31
  },
  "id": "the_pasted_link"
}
```

As you can see, it states that there are 5 comments, for this OGObject.

Than I use the *id_of_the_object* to collect the comments by requesting the following on the Explorer page:

*id_of_the_object*/comments

And I get an empty data object, without comments:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

But when I issue the same request for a OGObject of type **article**, the comments are there:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2017-03-30T12:21:48+0000",
      "from": {
        "name": "user",
        "id": "user_id"
      },
      "message": "some_message",
      "id": "message_id"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "blabla",
      "after": "blabla"
    }
  }
}
```

So the main question is, can I get comments from a OGObject of type **website** and how? Because it obviously doesn't work like the type article.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: Very good question! I am having the same problem.

Comment: Can you show me your code where you are requesting for comments?